# How to allow other users to play music in my application?

Tags: visual-studio

I am fairly new to Visual basic.net and I'm almost done working on an application (a chat bot). I've added a function which allows me to play music by telling the bot to "play music".

This is what I used

```
If input.contains("Play music") then 
txtbot.appendtext("Sure") 
My.computer.audio.play("C:\Users\rayqu\Music\VirInstrument1.wav")
```

Suppose someone else has installed my application and wants to play a song. Then the code above would not work for them, right? As the directory path in the code is based on my computer path and not their computer path. 
So what should I do to fix this? What should I do to allow other users to be able to play music from my app?

Comment: What type of application is this (GUI, console) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, `My.computer.audio.play(path)`takes a `.wav`or sound file. So, easy way:

- What about asking the user after saying *fine*, what is the path? Like "fine, what is the pathof your music?". In the end, it's a chatbot!

If the user, for example, says: *C:\Users\example1\Desktop\mySong.wav*, you could save that and pass it as an array to your function! Something like this!

```
array1='C:\Users\example1\Desktop\mySong.wav'
My.computer.audio.play(array1)
```

What do you think? It is something rough, but it adapts to any user, and it is simple (no need to implement the "open folder and select".

Comment: Oh great Idea!  Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: No problem! If it was useful, remember to upvote the answer! If it solved your problem completely, accept it as an answer! @Ray